# Outlook 2010 Hide Built-in Folders

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Orientation:
Outlook 2010 is open.  Extreme left pane displays my Inbox as well as folders I created - good.

It also displays built-in 'Folders?' RSS Feed, Start Search (Journal and Contacts) - bad.

I would like to hide these Outlook native folders because they take up vaulable space.

Any Ideas?

[image: Outlook 2010]

Comment: Have you tried deleting them?

Comment: How do you delete Journal, Contacts Calendar?  Being built-in, it's probably more a question of hiding them.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post, but for anybody interested, there is MFCMAPI which allows to hide folders and many more things:
[HowTo-Outlook - Hide, move or delete an Outlook folder via MFCMAPI](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/hidemovedeletemfcmapi.htm)

Answer (score -1):

Yah, this is a legitmate issue. The only solution I found was http://www.easy2sync.de/en/produkte/Hide-Outlook-Folders.php.

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping for a solution within Outlook, else a registry hack.

Comment: Viruses detected! By https://www.metadefender.com